# how to add hover effect on fa fa icons?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to change color on hover of fa fa icon but not changing? 
 http://jsfiddle.net/Lgvbbqeo/25/

```
.fa-arrow-circle-right {
float:right; 
color:white;
margin-right:10px;
}

.fa-fa-arrow-circle-right :hover{
color:#888888;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <button type="button" class="buttonl">View Locations<i class="fa   
  fa-arrow-circle-right fa-2x"></i>
  </button>
```

Comment: Remove the space. It should be `.fa-fa-arrow-circle-right:hover`.

Comment: removed space did not make a difference

Comment: Maybe the button or the button class is causing the issue?

Comment: You have an extra `fa-` in your hover style. It should be `.fa-arrow-circle-right :hover`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a little mistake in your selector
`.fa-fa-arrow-circle-right :hover` should be `.fa-arrow-circle-right :hover` or `.fa :hover` or `.fa .fa-arrow-circle-right :hover`

Comment: iv tried both ways ".fa-fa-arrow-circle-right:hover"

Comment: you have two classes assigned, to your icon, so you could use b oth as selector but you can't combine them with a `-` so `.fa .fa-arrow-circle-right:hover` or `.fa :hover` or `.fa-arrow-circle-right:hover` would fit

Comment: .fa changes the properties for my other icons, .fa-arrow-circle-right:hover and .fa-fa-arrow-circle-right:hover does not work either

Comment: @asaf you're putting the `:hover` on the icon and not the whole button. If you want the icon to change when you hover over the button, change your selector to something like `.buttonl:hover .fa-arrow-circle-right`.

Comment: .fa-arrow-circle-right:hover should work, if your your element has this class. If there is a misspelling in your html or css it wont work. You can give the button which contains this icon another class like `<button class="button grey-hover">...</button>` and in your css `.grey-hover:hover{...}`

Comment: @asaf ah ok hover only works if you hover the element you have the :hover assigned ;)

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
   .buttonl:hover .fa-arrow-circle-right
```

Comment: Be carful. This means everytime an element with class `buttonl` is hovered, all elements with class `fa-arrow-circle-right` will get the following css assigned. Means even if another button with this class is hovered the element with class `fa-arrow-circle-right` will get the css assigned.